# Extending jQuery Isotope plugin to layout elements horizontally

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to mimic the behavior seen here:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html

You can see that the elements are arranged nicely with a vertical boundary (fixed width). New elements are added in the bottom.
I would like to do the same, only that I need that the elements will be arranged with a horizontal boundary (fixed height).

I'll appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have checked lately but look at masonryHorizontal here:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#masonryhorizontal